# Decompose a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given a symmetric $30\times 30$ matrix 
$$A:=(0.55^{|i-j|})_{ij}, \quad 1\le i,j\le 30.$$
How to find a real $20\times 30$ matrix $H$ such that 
$$H^TH=A.$$

What makes this problem non-trivial to me is $H^T$ has more rows than columns.

If it's not feasible to find such a $H$ by naked eye, what would possibly be an efficient numerical algorithm to find it?

Thanks.

Comment: try the 3 by 3 case first, by hand. Part of this is the statement that the symmetric matrix is not full rank, with an upper bound on the rank.

Comment: It is a toeplitz matrix, if it helps. Are you sure that $A$ has rank deficit?

Comment: @user1551 it is full rank

Comment: @user251257 it is full rank

Comment: @user1551 I meant $H^T$, sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its solution doesn't exist (as explained by the current answer)

Answer (score 3):

If you take your matrix $A$ with 0.55 replaced by $t,$ with the understanding that $0 < t < 1.$ Next, take the matrix $P$ with the main diagonal all $1$ and the immediate upper diagonal all $-t,$ the congruent matrix
$$ M = P^T A P   $$
becomes the diagonal matrix with a single $M_{11} = 1$  and all other $M_{ii} = 1 - t^2.$

With $0 < t < 1$ this means that both $M$ and the original $A$ are positive definite.

Next, take $Q = P^{-1} \; \; .$

Let me typeset the 4 by 4 case. Below I am writing $Q^T M Q = A,$ where $M$ is diagonal positive, and there is a real positive square root matrix $\sqrt M \; .$ If we name $W = \sqrt M \; Q, \;$ we get $W^T W = A.$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0 \\
t&1&0&0 \\
t^2&t&1&0 \\
t^3&t^2&t&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0 \\
0&1-t^2&0&0 \\
0&0&1-t^2&0 \\
0&0&0&1-t^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&t&t^2&t^3 \\
0&1&t&t^2 \\
0&0&1&t \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&t&t^2&t^3 \\
t&1&t&t^2 \\
t^2&t&1&t \\
t^3&t^2&t&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Sorry, but since $A=H^TH$ and $H^T$ (not $H$, my apologies) has more rows than columns, I don't think $A$ is full rank.

Comment: @Vim What Will Jagy shows is that $(t^{|i-j|})_{ij}$ is positive definite when $0<t<1$. Therefore, $H$ does not exist because $H^TH$ is not full-rank.