# How to prove the positive-definiteness of a symmetric Toeplitz matrix like it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define a symmetric Toeplitz matrix by

H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2k(0) & k(s) & k(2s) & \dots  & k(NS)  \\
    k(s) & 2k(0) & k(s) & \dots  & k((N-1)S) \\
    k(2s) & k(s) & 2k(0) & \dots  & k((N-2)S) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots   \\
    k(Ns) & k((N-1)s) & k((N-2)s) & \dots & 2k(0)
\end{bmatrix}

k(.) is non-increasing function. e.g k(x) = $e^{-x}$

s, N are known constant.

How to prove that this matrix is positive-definite? Thanks a lot.

Comment: seethis recent question and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762141/decompose-a-symmetric-matrix/2762217#2762217

Comment: Thanks very much! But I don't think they are similar. As k(.) could be some piecewise constant function here.

Comment: the $s$ does not matter at all. Is $N$ the integer one smaller than the size of the matrix? Oh, and try the 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 sizes to see what happens

Comment: Yes, N is smaller than the size of the matrix. I saw that question, the thing I don't get is 'With 0<t<1 this means that both M and the original A are positive definite.'. I understand M is positive definite since it is the diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries being positive. But why A is also positive definite?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I don't know the exact expression of k(.), e.g. k(x) = 1 if x <= 5. k(x) = 0.5 if  5 < x <= 10 and so on. In this way, I am not sure if I can find P so that P^T H P = D while D is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries being positive. Any suggestions?

Comment: again, you should change the names to something without functions and do the 2 by 2 case, then 3 by 3, then 4 by 4. The top row of the 4 by 4 could be $2a,b,c,d$ such that $a \geq b \geq c \geq d \geq 0.$ As far as methods: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: Thanks for help! I understand this and I can get D from your reference link, but I cannot prove all the diagonal elements of D are positive, right? In this sense, I cannot prove H is positive definite.

Comment: well, except for some denominators involved, the diagonal terms appeard to come out exactly as the principal minor terms in   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion  I have a feeling the problem can be finished with this, as each pricincipal minor is simply a smaller matrix of the same type. This should help in giving information about the determinants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the $n\times n$ penta-band symmetric Toeplitz matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
2&1&1\\
1&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
1&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
 &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
 &      &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
 &      &      &1&1&2}.
$$
It has positive, negative and zero eigenvalues when $n=11$.

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is guaranteed to be positive definite if $a_{ij}=\varphi\left(\|x_i-x_j\|^2\right)$ for some *completely monotone* function $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ (i.e. a function such that $(-1)^m\frac{d^m\varphi}{dx^m}\ge0$ on $(0,\infty)$ for every $m\ge0$) and some set of distinct points $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ in some Euclidean space $\mathbb R^s$. This is known as *Schoenberg interpolation theorem*, which is a consequence of Bochner's characterisation of positive definite functions. See [chapter 15](http://books.google.com/books?id=mukLPHQSqLUC&pg=PA101&hl=zh-TW&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) of *A Course in Approximation Theory* by Cheney and Light or sec. 2.5 of this [book chapter](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf) for more details.

In your case, $\varphi(x)=e^{-\sqrt{x}}$ is known to be completely monotone. So, with this function $\varphi$, $A=H-k(0)I$ is positive definite and so is $H$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Question: it must be || xi -  xj ||^2 inside k(.) ? Could it be just || xi -  xj ||?

Comment: @Jin Yes, we need to use squared norm, but luckily, $\varphi(x)=e^{-\sqrt{x}}$ is completely monotone, so that $\varphi(x^2)=k(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$.